# Buttons and touchables on React Native lag with delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance, redux

I'm tying to create a basic e-shop in my application and it works fine. Every item in flatlist has 3 buttons ( `TouchableOpacity` ) to set quantity.
Those buttons are very slow: 1 second between clock and re-rendering . It looks like a long press but it's a simple click: [this is a simple video to show you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHF9n.jpg)

And this is the code in detail:

```
class Shop extends React.Component {
...
selectItem = (item, typeButton) => {
    if (item.qte >= 0) {
      switch (typeButton) {
        case 'plus':
          if (parseFloat(item.EshopPrice) <= parseFloat(this.state.score)) {
            this.setState({
              score: parseFloat(this.state.score).toFixed(2) - parseFloat(item.EshopPrice).toFixed(2),
            })
            const actionSum = { type: "INCREASE_SUM", value: item }
            this.props.dispatch(actionSum)
          } else {
            this.showToast();
          }
          break;
        case 'minus':
          if (this.props.totaleQte > 0) {
            item.qte = item.qte - 1
            this.setState({
              score: Number(parseFloat(item.EshopPrice).toFixed(2)) + this.state.score,
            })
            const actionSumMoin = { type: "DECREASE_SUM", value: item }
            this.props.dispatch(actionSumMoin)
          }
          break;
        case 'plus+':
          if (parseFloat(item.EshopPrice) <= parseFloat(this.state.score)) {

            item.qte = item.qte + 1
            this.setState({
              score: parseFloat(this.state.score).toFixed(2) - parseFloat(item.EshopPrice).toFixed(2),
            })
            const actionSum = { type: "SET_CURRENTSALE", value: item }
            this.props.dispatch(actionSum)
          } else {
            this.showToast();
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  };
...
render ()
...
return (...)
}
```

I call this function in a functional component in the same file which is the renderItem of a `flatlit` :

```
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <View style={StylesGift.buttonsContainer}>
          {
            item.qte === 0 ?
              <TouchableOpacity

                onPress={() => this.selectItem(item, 'plus+')}>
                <Text style={[StylesGift.itemQte, StylesGift.roundItemQte]}>+</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              :
              <View style={StylesGift.buttonsQteContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectItem(item, 'minus')}>
                  <Text style={[StylesGift.itemQte, StylesGift.roundItemQte]}>-</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Pressable
                  onPress={() => this.showModal(true, item)}>
                  <Text style={StylesGift.itemQte}>{item.qte}</Text>
                </Pressable>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectItem(item, 'plus')}>
                  <Text style={[StylesGift.itemQte, StylesGift.roundItemQte]}>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
          }
        </View>
    )
  }
```

I think the problem is in the `setState({score: ...})` and dispatching action to redux, because when I remove them all or remove one of them, the click becomes very fast and smooth.

This is the treatment on the reducer:

```
   case 'INCREASE_SUM':
      const productShopIndex = state.Data.findIndex(item => item.ProductID === action.value.ProductID)
      state.Data[productShopIndex].qte = state.Data[productShopIndex].qte + 1
      nextState = {
        ...state,
        sum: state.sum + parseFloat(action.value.EshopPrice),
      }
      
      return nextState || state
    case 'DECREASE_SUM':
      nextState = {
        ...state,
        totaleQte: action.value.qte === 0 ? state.totaleQte - 1 : state.totaleQte,
        sum: state.sum - parseFloat(action.value.EshopPrice),
      }

      return nextState || state
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is you are directly dispatching the global actions while pressing the buttons. The side effect of this is when you press + or -, the reducer will take some time to do computation and change the state(Thats why theres delay there since the JS thread is blocked). The simplest solution to this is for every counter, make the increment or decrement as local state and inside useEffect(or componentDidUpdate) sync that count with reducer after some debounce. The flow is:

1. Store the count value in local state inside the counter
2. Make debounce of like 500ms so that when user presses any button within this time,it will ignore the last count and only update when user leaves counter after the debounce time.
3. And sync with the global reducer after the debounce.

I came across similar situation recently. So hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when I comment this `//const actionSum = { type: "INCREASE_SUM", value: item }`
`// this.props.dispatch(actionSum)`
it's still slow with a delay ! only with `setState({score... })`

Comment: Then thats because you arfe changing the qty value and whenever it changes Flatlist re-renders. You can make separate component for renderItem and try to change th estate from inside that component.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @zedArt did you find how to solve it?